# Laravel 5.X - 'ErrorException' with message 'Use of undefined constant SUCCESS

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a laravel 5.X app and  I have defined the variable SUCCESS under the directory 'Helpers' in a file Responses.php as below

```
if (!defined("SUCCESS")) define("SUCCESS", 111);
```

I am trying to pass the SUCCESS in  the following snippet

```
    class UsersController extends Controller {

        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return Response
         */
        public function index() {


               $this->manageresponse(SUCCESS, X_WITH_WRONGCARD);

            //
        }
}
```

The code is refusing to execute by saying

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Use of undefined constant
>   SUCCESS - assumed 'SUCCESS'' in C:\Users\J...

Please let me know what should I do to access SUCCESS in my controller methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're defining the constant in a particular namespace, you need to access it through that namespace. Even if the constant isn't defined in a namespace, if you're accessing it from within a namespace, you need to use the global `\` or put a `use` statement at the top of your Controller file.

So if it's global, you could do this in your controller:

```
use Success;
```

Alternatively from anywhere within the file:

```
$this->manageresponse(\SUCCESS, X_WITH_WRONGCARD);
```

or if it's not global, you can do this...

```
use My\Namespace\Success;
```

Comment: Thanks. I defined it as a global. I tried \SUCCESS but the same error persists.

Comment: Part of what I'm getting at is that you need to provide more information than you have. The only other reason why it wouldn't be working is if your `Responses.php` file isn't running.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Laravel has no Helpers directory where all the files are autoloaded.

If this is the only thing you are doing, you could define it in `app/Http/Kernal.php` or `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

To do this "properly," you would need to create your own service provider: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers